# Как изменить значение переменой?

Tags: java

> "Количество шагов за выбранный месяц состовляет: 267477477
> Количество шагов за выбранный месяц состовляет: 267477477
> Среднее количество шагов в выбранном месяцу: 8915915
> Количество шагов за выбранный месяц состовляет: 0
> Количество километров пройденных в этом месяце: 0.0
> Количество шагов за выбранный месяц состовляет: 0
> Количество сожжённых килокалорий в этом месяце: 0.0
> Максимальная серия в этом месяце составляет 3 дней."

вот такой ответ при рандомных значениях и попытки сбора инфы, не могу понять почему не работает конвертер совсем, те он должен преобразовать шаги в км и шаги в каллории. А так же не получается изменить параметр  цели шагов, по дефолту он 10000 `int goalByStepsPerDay =10000;` я пытаюсь его переписать на пользовательское значение в `void changeStepGoal()` но оно не сохраняется и везде используется дефолтное значение.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StepTracker st = new StepTracker();
        MonthData md = new MonthData();


        System.out.println("Приветствуем вас в вашем персональном счетчике каллорий!");
        while (true) {
            printMenu();
            int i = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            if (i == 1) {
               st.addNewNumberStepsPerDay();
            } else if (i == 2) {
                md.changeStepGoal();
            } else if (i == 3) {
                st.printStatistic();
            } else if (i == 4) {
                System.out.println("Пока!");
                scanner.close();
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Этот пункт в разработке, а пока выберете любой другой уже разработанный (цифры от 1 до 4)");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Что бы вы хотели сделать? (Введите номер.)");
        System.out.println("1. Ввести количество шагов за определённый день.");
        System.out.println("2. Изменить цель по количеству шагов в день.");
        System.out.println("3. Hапечатать статистику за определённый месяц.");
        System.out.println("4. Bыйти из приложения.");
    }
}
```

КЛАСС StepTracker

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class StepTracker {
    Scanner scanner;
    Converter cv = new Converter();
    MonthData md = new MonthData();



    void addNewNumberStepsPerDay() {
        System.out.println("Введите номер месяца");
        int month = scanner.nextInt();
        if (month < 0 || month > 12) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка. Введите число от 1 до 12.");
            return;
        }
        // ввод и проверка номера месяца

        System.out.println("Введите день от 1 до 30 (включительно)");
        int day = scanner.nextInt();
        if (day < 1 || day > 30) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка. Введите число от 1 до 30.");
            return;
        }// ввод и проверка дня

        System.out.println("Введите количество шагов");
        int steps = scanner.nextInt();
        if (steps < 1) {
            System.out.println("Введите число больше 0");
            return;
        }
        md.daysInMonth[month - 1][day - 1] = steps;
        System.out.println("Значение сохранено!");// сохранение данных

    }

    void printStatistic() {
        System.out.println("Введите число месяца");
        int month=scanner.nextInt();
        if (month < 0 || month >12) {
            System.out.println("ОШИБКА, введите число от 1 до 12");
            return;
        }
        md.printDaysAndStepsFromMonth(month);
        md.sumStepsFromMonth(month);
        md.maxSteps(month);
        md.averageStepsInMonth(month);
        cv.convertToKm(month);// вывод пройденной за месяц дистанции в км
        cv.convertStepsToKilocalories(month);// вывод количества сожжённых килокалорий за месяц
        md.bestSeries(month);// вывод лучшей серии
                System.out.println(); //дополнительный перенос строки
    }
}
```

КЛАСС Converter

```
public class Converter {

    MonthData md = new MonthData();

    double kmK = 0.075;
    int formulaKiloKal = 50000;
    void convertToKm(int month) {
        double steps=md.sumStepsFromMonth(month);
        double stepsToKm =steps * kmK;
        System.out.println("Количество километров пройденных в этом месяце: " + stepsToKm);
    }

        //nado perevesti v km

    void convertStepsToKilocalories(int month){
        double kiloKal= md.sumStepsFromMonth(month) * formulaKiloKal;
        System.out.println("Количество сожжённых килокалорий в этом месяце: " + kiloKal); }
        //perevod v kkalaorii
    }
```

Хранение инфы и счет статистики

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MonthData {
    int[][] daysInMonth = new int[12][30];

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int goalByStepsPerDay =10000;
    void changeStepGoal() {
        System.out.println("Задайте новую цель");
        int newTarget= scanner.nextInt();
        if (newTarget<0) {
            System.out.println("Цель не может быть меньше 0");
            return;}
        goalByStepsPerDay=newTarget;
        }


    void printDaysAndStepsFromMonth(int month) {
        System.out.println("Введите номер месяца. (число от 1 до 12)");
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " день: " + daysInMonth[month-1][i]); //1 день: 3000 Вывод элементов массива в необходимом формате
        }
    }

    int sumStepsFromMonth(int month) {
        int sumSteps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            sumSteps = sumSteps + daysInMonth[month-1][i];
        System.out.println("Количество шагов за выбранный месяц состовляет: " + sumSteps);
        // подсчёт суммы элементов массива days[]

        return sumSteps;
    }

    void maxSteps(int month) {
        int maxSteps = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if (maxSteps < daysInMonth[month-1][i])// поиск максимального элемента
                maxSteps = daysInMonth[month-1][i];
        }
    }

    void bestSeries(int month) {
        int maxCount = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int steps : daysInMonth[month - 1]) {
            if (steps >= goalByStepsPerDay) {
                if (++count > maxCount) {
                    maxCount = count;
                }
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальная серия в этом месяце составляет " + maxCount + " дней.");
    }
     void averageStepsInMonth(int month) {
        int sumSteps = sumStepsFromMonth(month);
        int average = sumSteps/daysInMonth[1].length;
        System.out.println("Среднее количество шагов в выбранном месяцу: " + average);
     }
}
```

Comment: Советую почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

У вас без какой-либо необходимости используются разные экземпляры `MonthData` -- один создаётся в методе `main` -- и именно для него вы вызываете метод `changeStepGoal` и меняете количество шагов.
Также в классах `StepTracker` и `Converter` для чего-то создаются ещё два экземпляра `MonthData`, в которых ограничение на минимальное количество шагов не меняется.

Если у вас какие-то данные должны быть общими для нескольких классов -- проинициализируйте поле `MonthData` в экземплярах StepTracker / Converter через конструктор или сеттер.

```java
public class StepTracker {
    private MonthData md;
    private Converter converter;

    public StepTracker(MonthData md) {
        this.md = md;
        this.converter = new Converter(md);
    }
    // ...
}
```

```java
// main
MonthData md = new MonthData();
StepTracker st = new StepTracker(md);
// ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение, теперь корректно изменяется цель по шагам, я видимо недостаточно еще изучил тему конструкторов.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, можете поставить зеленую галочку